# Nothing appears when opening an HTML file with Folium

Tags: json, shapefile, folium

I have a shape file to visualize the speed zone here in NSW, and I have been trying to visualize this shape file using folium. It does not show anything even though there is no error. Furthermore, I was wondering how to put a filter to select and show what I choose. I really need your help to figure out this.

```
{"id": "454975", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"Type": "Default", "Status": "Existing", "Direction": "Both Directions", "Speed": "100 km/h"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[153.46108899977824, -28.19755700001067], [153.46126000030952, -28.197687999854413], [153.4614380004267, -28.19781099975431], [153.46151200009606, -28.197879000182386], [153.46179399974937, -28.19818000042449], [153.46199799960587, -28.198386000242166], [153.46225099976965, -28.198609000209512]]}}, {"id": "454976", "type": 

"Feature", "properties": {"Type": "Default", "Status": "Existing", "Direction": "Both Directions", "Speed": "100 km/h"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[153.46225099976965, -28.198609000209512], [153.46241500001867, -28.198501999878136], [153.46249099978732, -28.198458000113128], [153.46258399997743, -28.198419999750193], [153.4626800004706, -28.198387000144297], [153.4627489995125, -28.198369999701203]]}}, {"id": "454977", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"Type": "Default", "Status": "Existing", "Direction": "Both Directions", 

"Speed": "100 km/h"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[153.461306000118, -28.18934200005291], [153.46136499973215, -28.18926000045827], [153.46172900004987, -28.188283000085022], [153.46185800034633, -28.187983999798508], [153.46194200050982, -28.18781200030131]]}}, {"id": "454978", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"Type": "Default", "Status": "Existing", "Direction": "Both Directions", "Speed": "100 km/h"}, "geometry": 

{"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[153.51829100026293, -28.93218699955592], [153.51844899969205, -28.932217000173697], [153.51847599982918, -28.932222000296093], [153.51861500025464, -28.932248999807882]]}}, {"id": "454979", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"Type": "Default", "Status": "Existing", "Direction": "Both Directions", "Speed": "100 km/h"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[153.51861500025464, -28.932248999807882], [153.51869599970837, -28.932264000100222]]}}, {"id": "454980", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"Type": "Default", "Status": "Existing", "Direction": "Both Directions", "Speed": "100 km/h"}, "geometry": {"type": 

"LineString", "coordinates": [[153.52177699994152, -28.92458000009017], [153.52181000016918, -28.924675000347495], [153.52184399994584, -28.92479700010719], [153.52188000046084, -28.92498200041054], [153.52190600026015, -28.925156999846372], [153.52192200046318, -28.925332999527797], [153.52193499971534, -28.925566000112298], [153.52193800050085, -28.925783000145874], [153.52193400048648, -28.925975999835043], [153.52190300010776, -28.926451000399428], [153.5218670004436, -28.926700999758378], [153.5217969996899, -28.92703599975639], [153.52175299984202, -28.92719400004926], [153.52167899968006, -28.92737900023263], [153.52161199964922, -28.927517999960315], [153.52151599988957, -28.927682999743666], [153.52142600003623, -28.927808000389298], [153.521187999885, -28.928105999721936], [153.52105400014966, -28.928232000250876], [153.52031499953316, -28.92884699981758], [153.52017200007805, -28.928956999551758], [153.52005299965734, -28.929057000144194], [153.51997799970388, -28.929130000250808], [153.5199029999857, -28.929216000171547], [153.51979199972916, -28.929387999760714], [153.51974000030776, -28.929499999918225], [153.5197189997404, -28.929555999916847], [153.51964400026353, -28.92984099971861], [153.51943799967867, -28.930796999568923], [153.51935999998076, -28.931100999700718], [153.51927299987847, -28.93134799981182], [153.51917200041348, -28.931586999686292], [153.5190789999957, -28.931781999696796], [153.51894499950401, -28.93203399970778], [153.51884599969313, -28.932175999677217], [153.51877600005997, -28.93222999992459], [153.5187369999621, -28.932249000111874], [153.51869599970837, -28.932264000100222]]}}
```

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_file)

# Create a folium map centered at the shapefile's center
m = folium.Map(location=[-33.8688, 151.2093], zoom_start=12)

# Convert the GeoDataFrame to GeoJSON format
gdf_json = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326").to_json()

gdf_dict = json.loads(gdf_json)

for feature in gdf_dict["features"]:
        geometrytype = feature.get('geometry',{}).get('type')
        coordinates = feature.get('geometry', {}).get('coordinates')
        Type = feature.get('properties', {}).get('Type')
        Status = feature.get('properties', {}).get('Status')
        Direction = feature.get('properties', {}).get('Direction')
        Speed = feature.get('properties', {}).get('Speed')

        color = 'green'  # Default color if speed is not specified
        if Speed == '40 km/h':
            color = '#FF000000'
        elif Speed == '50 km/h':
            color = '#FF000000'

        geojson = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Type": Type,
                "Status": Status,
                "Direction": Direction,
                "Speed": Speed         
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type": geometrytype,
                "coordinates": coordinates
            }
        }

        folium.GeoJson(
            geojson,
            style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': color, 'color': color},
        ).add_to(m)

m.save("map6.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you presented was geopandas geometry, I have added a column that converts it to a list of latitudes and longitudes so that it can be used for the polyline. I am drawing a polyline on the map by looping through that geopandas data frame. The conversion to a list of latitudes and longitudes was based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433460/extracting-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-as-list-from-linestring-in-geopandas).

```
import io
import geopandas as gpd

data = '''
{"id": "454975", "type": ,...}
'''

gdf = gpd.read_file(io.StringIO(data))

import folium
from folium import plugins

def f(frame):
    xy = frame.geometry.xy
    longs = xy[0].tolist()
    lats = xy[1].tolist()
    return [list(z) for z in zip(lats, longs)]

gdf['coords'] = gdf.apply(f, axis=1)

# Create a folium map centered at the shapefile's center
m = folium.Map(location=[-28.19755700001067, 153.46108899977824], zoom_start=15)

for row in gdf.itertuples():
    if row.Speed == '100 km/h':
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color='green'
    folium.PolyLine(
        row.coords,
        weight=5,
        color=color,
    ).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]